# Will database security configurations (Logins etc.) persist through upgrade from SQL Server 2014 Express to SQL Server 2017 Express?

Tags: sql-server

Will database security configurations (Logins etc.) persist through upgrade from SQL Server 2014 Express to SQL Server 2017 Express?

I am running a database instance on SQL Server 2014 Express edition and would like to move to the SQL Server 2017 Express edition but I fear that security credentials might get lost.

This is a production environment so I'm assuming someone will answer that I should do a test environment which I'm unsure how to setup. Without testing would I need to worry about any security information being reverted? I've tried to backup and restore the database to a separate instance of SQL Server 2017 evaluation but the security information had to be redone of course and the users were able to see the instance but not the database within. Any thoughts?

First time asking a question on here so don't kill me if I didn't follow a certain protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran the upgrade of the SQL Server from the 2014 version to the 2017 version and I can confirm that security configurations are transferred over to the new version. As well when you upgrade your edition of the server security configurations also persist.